# How to use Masonry with AngularJS template?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, jquery-masonry

Hello I Want to use masonry in `AngularJS`. I want to adjust div from left to right in container. According to their documentation we can use it simply using

```
<div class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".item", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I have used this in Angular like

```
<div class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": "#masonry", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
     <div id="masonry" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="comment in comments.data" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
     <div id="masonry" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="comment in comments.data" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
     <div id="masonry" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="comment in comments.data" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
</div>
```

I want these div to autoadjust from left to right(simliar to Isotope's masonry effect). using This for first time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wrapper made for this:

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

A quick example of how to use it:

```
<div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
</div>
```